# Cannot perform ‘set’ on a proxy that has been revoked

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

We are using a skill bot and root bot. Skill bot is a Microsoft del based bot. Root bot is composer based bot. When root bot connects with skill, sometimes towards the end, we see error saying cannot perform set on proxy that has been revoked. We are unsure of why this is occurring and this is happening intermittently. Looking at the conversation did not help but in the storage the conversation state gets deleted

We tried adding logs and tracing activities. We noticed that it happens at the end of one conversation and beginning of next between root and skill.